# where would npm install the modules in Macbook file system?

Tags: javascript, macos, npm, underscore.js, npm-install

I just installed module `underscore js` using `npm install underscore`. I want to know how and where NPM would store that module so I can import that module in my `.js` file.

Comment: Did you run `npm -g install underscore`?  The `-g` would matter.

Comment: You usually don't need to know where npm install things to use them. It looks like are misunderstanding the whole import process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `npm install` without the `-g` flag will install the modules in the current directory under `node_modules`

Comment: I installed without  `-g` but can't find it in the current directory. As I am not working in node app.

Comment: You are not working in the node app? I'm not sure what you mean by that

Answer (score 0):

Using `npm install -g`, it would install at following address on computer(MAC)

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```